# SDL Web 8 Installation - licensing issue

Tags: installation, licensing

After installing the SDL web 8 against the provided license i am getting below  error -

> "This computer has more CPUs than allowed by the license"

Below is the lenicse term by SDL-

> Non-hostname bound  license key for 4 CPU ,2 named users, all other
>   options included, valid until November 30, 2016. We can reuse this
>   license for all these developer requests. Named “Web 8 Developer
>   License”

.

and below is the processor info of my machine -

> Intel(R)Xeon(R)CPU 3565@3193 Mhz, 4 Core(4), 8 LogicalProcessor(s)

Pleasse help and suggest me . See the below screenshots for more detail

[image: Error Screenshot]

[image: Machine Information]

Comment: 4 CPUs in the license actually mean 4 logical cores. If you're running a virtual machine change the settings to show less CPUs

Comment: Hi Nuno , we are not running a virtual machine. please suggest in that case. In Device manager , I am seeing 8 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU processors installed. Can i uninstall some of them ?

Answer (score 4):

As specified in the processor info, your machine has 8 logical processors. That's more than allowed by your license.

The processor info also states that there are 4 Cores. That probably means that HyperThreading is enabled. This is something you may be able to disable in the BIOS/UEFI settings.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to disable some of your cores in Windows:

1. Press Ctrl+R
2. Type in **msconfig** and click on OK
3. In Boot tab select Advanced options
4. Select number of cores you want to use during Windows start
5. Restart your PC

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As nuno and @rick  mentioned logical processors also counts so you have 8 processors and license is valid for 4.

Not sure about legality(SDL) but This is nice article where you can follow steps to disable Intel Hyper-threading in HP based BIOS.

http://in.pcmag.com/cpus-components/71647/feature/how-to-disable-hyperthreading

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by everybody, you have 8 logical processors and the license is valid for 4 processors, that is the cause of error.

This situation can arise, when the machine that you are having has two processors (in your case one processor 3.2 GHz, and other processor 3193 MHz) with 4 cores which will translate to 8 logical processor.

You will have to request a new license with 8 processor and use it. That should resolve the issue.